# Java Mouse Listener - Can event type be detected inside of an event?

Tags: java, swing, events, listener, mouse

I have bunch of JLabel tiles with mouseListeners set to them like this:

```
tile.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){

   Boolean isOnTile = false;

   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                        
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                        isOnTile = true;
                        while(true && isOnTile) {
                            try {
                                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                                e1.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            
                            System.out.println("a");
                        }   
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                        isOnTile = false;
                    }

});
```

Can i achieve the effect that this code (which isn't working) suggests? I want to exit the loop after the mouse is being taken off a JLabel. This doesn't work - after i take off the mouse the loop continues infinitely anyway. Is there a way to detect in which event, function i'm inside in the event function? I looked at e. functions but looks like there isn't one that has this functionality.

Comment: Why do you need the loop?  `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited` should tell you everything you need

Comment: I want to infinitely do something while mouse is on a specific tile, then stop when it isnt, or when i move to another tile then the effect switches just for that one.

Comment: If this can be achieved without loops then i'm opened for suggestions

Comment: You use a SwingTimer, which repeatedly calls its actionPerformed method, start it when the mouse enters the region and stop it when it leaves. No loops directly needed.

Comment: Thank you it works, i declared timer, setrepeats on true start in entered and stop in exited